# How to prove a recursive sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have $f(x+1)-f(x)=\dfrac {-1}{x^2+x}$ and I want to prove it is bounded: $f(x)< 1$ for all $x>0$. If f(1)=1

I've tried induction but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

*Remark:* Since the answer was typed, the recurrence has been changed to $f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+x}$. Minor sign modifications should then be made below, but the structure of the answer does not change.

We have 
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}.$$
Similarly, 
$$f(x+2)=f(x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+2}=f(x)+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+2}.$$
Similarly,
$$f(x+3)=f(x+2)+\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x+3}=f(x)+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+3}.$$
And so on. In general
$$f(x+n)=f(x+n-1)+\frac{1}{x+n-1}-\frac{1}{x+n}=f(x)+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+n}.$$
This shows boundedness. To give an explicit bound, we further information.

Comment: How did know to split up the fraction so easily.

Comment: It is very standard, you probably have seen it in partial fractions, but also the trick comes up in certain telescoping series. The most common one is $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.